# R: Count of consecutive identical values across columns using RLE

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using R. I have a data frame that consists of a row for each player and then columns representing each month and a number of points they earned (illustrative data with random values below). I would like to add a new column (Points$ConsecutiveShutouts) that contains the longest consecutive streak for a specified point total over say the past 5 months.

```
Points <- data.frame("Player" = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Gamma"), "MayPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))), "JunPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))), "JulPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))), "AugPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))), "SepPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))), "OctPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))), "NovPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))),"DecPts" = c(floor(runif(7, 0, 3))))

Player MayPts JunPts JulPts AugPts SepPts OctPts NovPts DecPts
Alpha      0      0      1      0      2      2      2      0
Beta       1      0      1      1      1      1      1      2
Charlie    1      2      2      0      2      1      1      0
Delta      0      1      1      2      2      2      0      0
Echo       1      1      0      2      1      2      0      1
Foxtrot    1      0      0      0      0      0      2      1
Gamma      2      0      1      1      0      2      0      1
```

I have tried using rle(points):

```
# Establish the start and end months
StartMonth <- which(colnames(Points) == "SepPts")
EndMonth <- which(colnames(Points) == "DecPts")

# Find total of consecutive months with 0 points
Points$ConsecutiveShutOuts <- max(rel(Points[ ,StartMonth:EndMonth] == 0), lengths[!values])
```

Doing this, I end up with the error "'X' must be a vector of an atomic type"

Any advice on what I am doing wrong and how I can fix? Or alternative approaches?

Thanks in advance! [Beginner here, so hopefully I followed the correct approach to question asking :)]

Comment: This may be a lot easier to work with if you have a 'long' dataset that is just 3 columns - 1) Player 2) Month 3) Pts - then you can just apply `rle` or something else to the `Pts` column alone.

Answer (score 1):

I would use long form as well. I would first create a function like this.

```
myfun <- function(series,value){
    tmp <- rle(series); runs <- tmp$lengths[tmp$values == value]
    if (length(runs)==0) return(0)
    else return(max(runs))
}
```

Using tidyr/dplyr, you can proceed as

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Points %>%
  gather(months,Pts,MayPts:DecPts) %>%
  group_by(Player) %>%
  summarise(x=myfun(tail(Pts,5),0))
# Past 5 month, number of consecutive zeros for each player.
```

Of course, you can join the result to the original wide-form data frame if you'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum based upon some condition (e.g., only summing points higher than 1), you can melt and restrict the summation only to rows greater than that value.

```
Points <- as.data.table(Points)
Points <- melt(Points, id="Player", variable.name = "Month", value.name = "PTs") 
Points <- Points[PTs>1, list(PTs = sum(PTs, na.rm=TRUE)), by="Player"] #change ">1" if you prefer a different value
```

Comment: might be worth adding to your answer the fact you're using `library(data.table)`